# Postgres - How would I generate a daily budget by day from a given overall budget and start date/end date

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, if I had the following table:

```
campaign   | budget     | start_date  | end_date
-----------|------------|-------------|------------
Microsoft  | 25400      | 2018-04-01  | 2018-06-30
VMWare     | 12340      | 2018-04-01  | 2018-06-01
```

How would I use the start date and end date to give me a number of days the campaign will be active, so that I may divide that number by the overall budget to get the daily budget? And I wish to fit that in a date series between 2018-04-01 and 2018-06-30

I would hope to get a table like this:

```
date       | daily_budget
-----------|--------------
2018-04-01 | 486
2018-04-02 | 486
2018-04-03 | 486
(...)
2018-06-29 | 282
2018-06-30 | 282
```

Comment: What have you tried? What are your current efforts?

Comment: @Nicarus just have the equation `SUM(budget/abs(end_date-start_date)) AS daily_budget` but I don't know how to put that in a range between 04-01 and 06-30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all dates in a range, you would probably use a recursive CTE.  To get days in an interval, you can just subtract, and to sum the different campaigns, just group by date.  [This SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/01a67/14) seems to be what you're looking for (code below).

```
WITH RECURSIVE calendar(
  campaign
  , budget_date
  , end_date
) AS
(
    SELECT 
      campaign
      , start_date budget_date
      , end_date 
    FROM 
      budgetTotal
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
      c.campaign
      , c.budget_date + 1
      , c.end_date
    FROM 
      calendar c 
    WHERE 
      c.budget_date < c.end_date
  )
SELECT 
  c.budget_date 
  , ROUND(
      SUM(bt.budget / (bt.end_date - bt.start_date))
      , 2
  ) dailyBudget 
 FROM 
   budgetTotal bt
 JOIN 
   calendar c
   ON 
   c.budget_date BETWEEN bt.start_date AND bt.end_date
   AND 
   c.campaign = bt.campaign
 GROUP BY 
   c.budget_date
 ORDER BY 
   c.budget_date
```

Comment: Why not `generate_series(start_date, end_date, '1 day')`?

Comment: @Nicarus  (+1) Recursive CTE works in a number of SQL flavors and is a nice tool to have in one's kit.  I can edit your suggestion in as another option if you don't want to provide an answer yourself.

Comment: Feel free to edit it in. I will not answer because I feel the question is low quality since the OP did not provide any evidence of attempts or effort on their own.